# Why is my json response being parsed as an empty array?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-httpclient

So this is very hard to explain to me, but I am using httpclient to retrieve information from the backend. I got this json response from them

```
[{"roomTypes":[{"rooms":[{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":312997.7894394667116560,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"8d11e1a9-e2fc-403d-bd9f-905c6369da3c","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":312950.2502855421267970,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","name":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":312997.7894394667116560,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"4f523914-afd7-4e35-b89e-d9925e3eee12","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":312950.2502855421267970,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","name":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":312997.7894394667116560,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"41711efc-8559-4a09-88b1-2ee23abe061c","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":312950.2502855421267970,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","name":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":366241.6418350017537360,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"20234058-38b4-4f17-ae04-9bc6a3ae950c","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":366194.1026810771688770,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - DOBLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - DOBLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":366241.6418350017537360,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"baf1b6ac-c873-4f91-94e8-6699f87b9358","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":366194.1026810771688770,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - DOBLE STANDARD - ","name":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - DOBLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":419485.4942305367958160,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"584896cb-fde3-4abb-be0b-2026fc8293a5","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":419485.4942305367958160,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE STANDARD - DOBLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE STANDARD - DOBLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":449482.7003569498418450,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"beed2c36-738f-4f13-959c-5491bbe443a3","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":449435.1612030252569860,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":449482.7003569498418450,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"b8d87bbe-fcf9-4578-aa09-1ea143095346","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":449435.1612030252569860,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","name":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":502726.5527524848839250,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"f1904525-fe01-4aef-a94a-93220eb90e66","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":502679.0135985602990660,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE STANDARD - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE STANDARD - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":506006.7543732812391960,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"6286c66a-7fb3-4e83-b12a-0e53841a3e93","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":506006.7543732812391960,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":506006.7543732812391960,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"41405355-e598-4783-bab5-499a0d784322","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":506006.7543732812391960,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","name":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":559250.6067688162812760,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"f62926a3-ee51-4748-872f-842c978546a8","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":559250.6067688162812760,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE STANDARD - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE STANDARD - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":585967.6112744329720340,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"7dba8fbb-a0f4-4370-9bfd-b7873092c449","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":585920.0721205083871750,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"TRIPLE STANDARD - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","name":"TRIPLE STANDARD - TRIPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":642491.6652907643693850,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"02fb3a63-4c51-44a9-a706-ededdcae1b86","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":642491.6652907643693850,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"TRIPLE STANDARD - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","name":"TRIPLE STANDARD - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":699015.7193070957667360,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"cfdd4dab-5006-43f7-8c6b-759613bd730a","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":699015.7193070957667360,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"CUADRUPLE STANDARD - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","name":"CUADRUPLE STANDARD - CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","p":11}],"adults":0,"children":0,"ages":null,"cod":"Combined","name":"Combined","requested":1,"p":11}],"p":11,"cod":"JP253924","details":{"name":"Hostal Posada San Martín","thumbnail":null,"rating":null,"address":null,"bestsale":null,"lat":null,"lon":null,"c":"JP253924","p":11}}]
```

Now, the thing is that the path roomTypes=>rooms is being parsed as an empty array. = []

So, I have tried doing the `post<INTERFACE>` with the corresponding model, with no success.

Now, I have tried to get the text response, and then use javascript to parse it. Which ended up being vering confusing becuase if i console.log it directly works but if I use a variable it won't work:

```
            const reserv = JSON.parse(reservations);
            console.log(JSON.parse(reservations));
            console.log(reserv);
```

Outputs:
[image]

The worst thing about this is that I cannot replicate it in the console from the browser. In that it just parses perfectly.

I would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks

EDIT:

The calling class:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configuration: Configuration) {
}        
    this.service.DoNonCachedSearch(requProv).toPromise().then(function (reservations: any)  {
                const reserv = JSON.parse(reservations);
                console.log(JSON.parse(reservations));
                console.log(reserv);
            });
```

In the service:

```
                DoNonCachedSearch(request) {
    return this.http
               .post(
                   this.configuration.apiUrlBase +
                   'DoNonCachedSearch'
                   request, {responseType: 'text'},
               );

}
```

EDIT 2:

Another test case:

```
[{"roomTypes":[{"rooms":[{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":156498.8947197333558280,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"d3708f31-9428-455b-aa87-4f333ac79026","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":156498.8947197333558280,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","name":"DOBLE CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":156498.8947197333558280,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"3b355dee-4565-4aeb-8588-6347fd147de0","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":156498.8947197333558280,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","name":"HABITACIÓN 2 CAMAS CON CUARTO DE BAÑO COMPARTIDO - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":209742.7471152683979080,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"927d6fdd-ebf8-4b43-9bc5-6495f9f22795","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":209742.7471152683979080,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"DOBLE STANDARD - ","name":"DOBLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"SA","name":"Sólo Alojamiento","promo":[],"price":246347.8956371987393380,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"292bb24a-071e-408a-8453-371749319698","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":246347.8956371987393380,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"APARTAMENTO STANDARD - ","name":"APARTAMENTO STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":292983.8056372164860170,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"eb5c9e08-592f-4cac-b1c6-240429c459ed","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":292983.8056372164860170,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"TRIPLE STANDARD - ","name":"TRIPLE STANDARD - ","p":11},{"boards":[{"cod":"AD","name":"Alojamiento y Desayuno","promo":[],"price":349507.8596535478833680,"currency":"COP","ratekey":"b864b217-eceb-4c5f-a71e-4d34dba76985","CancellationPolicy":[{"id":0,"date":"2020-01-21T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":-1,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":0.0,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"P"},{"id":0,"date":"2020-02-10T00:00:00","dateOfQuery":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","checkIn":"2020-03-12T00:00:00","type":"BA","remainingDays":18,"daysToCheckin":0,"fee":349507.8596535478833680,"currency":"COP","unitQuantity":0.0,"unit":"M"}],"refCancellationPolicy":null,"p":11,"comission":0.0,"package":false,"dailyRate":null}],"cod":"CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","name":"CUADRUPLE STANDARD - ","p":11}],"adults":0,"children":0,"ages":null,"cod":"Combined","name":"Combined","requested":1,"p":11}],"p":11,"cod":"JP253924","details":{"name":"Hostal Posada San Martín","thumbnail":null,"rating":null,"address":null,"bestsale":null,"lat":null,"lon":null,"c":"JP253924","p":11}}]
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: `HttpClient` parse data as JSON by default. You don't need to use `JSON.parse()` on it.

Comment: to squash some confusion console log will show "live data" as in it will change when the var you logged is resolved. It won't necessarily show you what the var is at that specific point in time. See "Logging Objects" section in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: can you show more code about how you set the "reservations" var? or your http request code?

Comment: Sure, will update the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
 DoNonCachedSearch(request) {
    return this.http
               .post(
                   this.configuration.apiUrlBase +
                   'DoNonCachedSearch'
                   request, {responseType: 'text'},
               ).then(res => res.json());

}
```

Comment: Http.post is an observable. I cannot use then with it. And if I try post().toPromise().then(res=>res.json()) I get the error "String.json() is not a valid method"

Comment: i'ts true sorry

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an encoding issue to me. Your strings seem to contain Unicode characters. If they are interpreted as ASCII the parser might stumble over it.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I was accessing the variable in another component that was modifying...

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to execute a HttpPost call. From Angular 2 and above, it is good and easy to use 
Observable. No need to convert to promise and continue further logic.

In your service use the below code

```
 public DoNonCachedSearch(request: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.configuration.apiUrlBase}DoNonCachedSearch`;
    return this.http.post(url, request,{responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

to invoke above method which is in the service, use the below code

```
  this.service.DoNonCachedSearch(requProv)    
    .subscribe(data =>
        {
            let responseData= data;
            console.log(responseData);
        });
```

parsing of JSON will be taken care automatically by angular.

hope this solves your issue.